# A single Event Listener for the various <a> elements

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in `JavaScript` to have only one single listener for all `<a>` elements?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

That listener should take a value (e.g. `#4`) to update some div.

Comment: JQuery offers easy ways through the use of on delegates to wire up single handlers for a group of elements.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Comment: @TGH without jQuery.

Comment: Sure, just bind a listener to the `ul`, and then do `event.target.hash` to get the number. http://jsfiddle.net/fdvacpz9/

Comment: @squint Cool. That's what I wanted to hear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this piece of code helps you out, the listener attached on the ul tag is now catching all the click events on its children and parsing out their href values. You might want to use a jquery lib to further parse out the #hrefvalue.

```
  <ul>
<li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#5">5</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].addEventListener("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
alert(e.target.href);
});
</script>
```

Comment: `e.target` is not cross platform, try `e.target || e.srcElement`